# cross compile protobuf 2.5.0 for Android on Centos 7

Tags: android, c++, qt, protocol-buffers, centos7

I would like to run a Qt Console Application written in C++ that includes the use of protobuf on a android phone.

Therefore, I need to crosscompile protobuf for a arm architecture. I have been following this script.

https://gist.github.com/helayzhang/9034454

This is my configure command:

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/home/staff/Desktop/proto_arm --build=armv7- android-linux-android --host=armv7-android-linux-android --target=armv7-android-linux-android --enable-cross-compile --with-protoc=/home/staff/Desktop/proto_arm/protoc CXXFLAGS="$(pkg-config --cflags protobuf)" LIBS="$(pkg-config --libs protobuf)"
```

My problems are cross-compilation option is ignored

```
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
```

and I am not sure whether I am building for the right architecture. My phone supports ABIs arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a and armeabi, the OS is android 6 marshmallow

I am grateful for every advice!

Here is a link to my config.log file
[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ceygsjduyen01d7rwabwp/config.log?dl=0&oref=e&r=AAUJ7mflXe-L8MjLmxNLEk6d_LAK2MBgmrSmWl9dQBikL2vtZh2wLIyYH2VpiZD7T5y97ODQECYz79rkzk2YT8PcZUzNLGsP66Oe7673a3zwWS8a_djsX0ICRZycV9zZ0aa8843dT5jdJt63YEBAhsgPlsrl0Gp-ktEek-tKTbdAMg&sm=1)

Comment: show us your configure script log or position

Comment: I added a link to config.log in the description

Answer (score 1):

I was able to compile protobuf with this scipt:

```
#!/bin/bash
export NDK=/media/qt5-qwt6/ndk10/android-ndk-r10e
export SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-arm

export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64

export PATH=$PATH:$TOOLCHAIN/bin

export CC="$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot $SYSROOT"
export CXX="$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot $SYSROOT"
export CXXSTL=$NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9

function build_one
{
mkdir build

./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/build \
--host=arm-linux-androideabi \
--with-sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--enable-static \
--disable-shared \
--enable-cross-compile \
--with-protoc=protoc \
CFLAGS="-march=armv7-a" \
CXXFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -I$CXXSTL/include -I$CXXSTL/libs/armeabi-v7a/include  -L$CXXSTL/libs/armeabi-v7a/ -lgnustl_static"

make clean
make
make install
}

CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one

# Inspect the library architecture specific information
# arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -A build/lib/libprotobuf-lite.a
```